# Добавить свое поле в запрос SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста есть код, который делает копию полей в таблице.

```
<?php
$date = date("d.m.Y G:i");
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "*";
$username = "*";
$password = "*";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
$sql = "insert into order_products( name, price, id_products, amount, image) select name, price, id_products, amount, image from order_products where id_order=1";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
mysqli_close($conn);
header("Location: /");
?>
```

Еще есть столбец `id_order`, в это поле нужно записать свое значение.
Подскажите как это сделать. Спасибо.

Comment: `select name, price, id_products, amount, image, 42 from ...`?

Comment: @u_mulder как всегда пришли на помощь) Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте нужное значение в список полей селекта:

```
$sql = "insert into order_products( name, price, id_products, amount, image, id_order) select name, price, id_products, amount, image, 42 from order_products where id_order=1";
```

Здесь `42` ид заказа и в части `insert` добавлено поле `id_order`.